# Can't access my ubuntu 16 from outside my network

Tags: networking, server, ssh, apache2

I have searched all around the internet, but I can't solve my problem. I always find posts that refer to port forwarding but I think this is not my problem at all.

I have a Macbook Pro in which I have installed an ampps server and I have my website running fine. I can connect to it inside or outside my network without any problem.

I have another laptop running Ubuntu in which I have installed openSSH, apache2, mysql and php. I have access to it without any problems from my network but from outside I can't connect.

On both, I'm using port 80.

Also, I have checked on multiple sites that allow you to see if your port is forwarded, but all of them say that my port is not forwarded even with my ampps server running perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use on both servers port 80 and your port 80 from your router is forwarded to your macbook pro.

You have following options:

1. to get another public IP address and place your ubuntu server in the new subnet and forward port 80 to your ubuntu server
2. Combine both macbook pro and ubuntu machine sites into one server installation. You can configure Web server Apache to respond to two domain names on the same ip address you are using now. The apache will react to the domain typed in the address bar and respond with the respective site. In this case you will need to forward the port 80 to your new combined server.
3. For ubuntu server use another port - for instance 8080 and forward this port to your ubuntu machine. You can also forward external port 8080 to the port 80 of your ubuntu server. The external port 80 would be forwarded to port 80 of your macbook pro.
4. Forward port 80 to your ubuntu server and in Apache setup for a second domain a reverse proxy, which will forward requests for the macbook site to your macbook pro.

The question is whether the sites will be publicly available to anyone or will be used just by you. For the publicly available sites you have to take option 1, option 2 or option 4, for the sites accessed by you the option No. 3 is the most viable.

Comment: Maybe 4th option is available: Forward port 80 to the Ubuntu server and setup certain Apache's virtual host to work as reverse proxy for the other server.

Comment: Yes it is possible also. Depending on the skills of the installer. A reverse proxy is a good idea indeed. Quite difficult to setup, but possible

Answer (score 0):

To connect from outside network, you have to use **Public IP**. If you are using local IP address (Like 192.168.xx.xx ) it will work fine inside the local network, but if you are accessing it from outside the network, use Public IP.